# Adjust place of downloading buttons of a DT table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

[please see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK54u.png)
I have a DT table in the shiny. I added buttons for downloading the content of the table (Copy, CSV, Excel, PDF). But I would like to change the distance between the first button and "show number of entries" (please see the attached picture and below code). How can I set the distance between the first button and "show entries"?

```
output$fancyTable<- renderDataTable ({    
DT::datatable(data, extensions = "Buttons", options = list(paging = TRUE, scrollX=TRUE, searching = TRUE, ordering = TRUE,dom = 'l<"sep">Bfrtip',

                                 buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
                                 pageLength=5,
                                 lengthMenu=c(5,10,20,100) ))
```

here is my UI code for the table:

```
 mainPanel(
                 # actionButton("download1", "Download table"),
                  tags$head(
                   tags$style(HTML("
                .sep {
                   width: 20px;
                   }
                     "))
                       ),
                 DT::dataTableOutput("fancyTable"),
                 tags$hr(),
                 plotlyOutput("fancyPlot"
                              ,width = "auto"
                              , height = "auto"
                 ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9v17.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `dom = 'l<"sep">Bfrtip'` and this will add a `div` between `l` and `B` having class `sep`. Then in your shiny app define the CSS for the `sep` class:

```css
.sep {
  width: 20px;
  height: 1px;
  float: left;
}
```

You can set this CSS in the Shiny UI as below:

```r
tags$head(
  tags$style(HTML("
    .sep {
      width: 20px;
      height: 1px;
      float: left;
    }
  "))
)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I have never used CSS in the shiny app, so I don't know where I should add it, But I just tried it, and I got an error about "px" which was "unexpected token".

Comment: @shamimash Ok. I edited my answer to show you the way.

Comment: I edited my question based on your answer, but it didn't change, the output is the same.

Comment: @shamimash Indeed. I've just edited my answer to add some CSS properties. This works for me now.